# URL Mapping prefix in Grails

Tags: grails, url-routing

Recently, I'm trying to migrating my application from CakePHP to Grails. So far it's been a smooth sailing, everything I can do with CakePHP, I can do it with much less code in Grails. However, I have one question :

In CakePHP, there's an URL Prefix feature that enables you to give prefix to a certain action url, for example, if I have these actions in my controller :

> **PostController**
>   admin_add
>   admin_edit
>   admin_delete

I can simply access it from the URL :

> mysite/admin/post/add
>   mysite/admin/post/edit/1
>   mysite/admin/post/delete/2

instead of:

> mysite/post/admin_add
>   mysite/post/admin_edit/1
>   mysite/post/admin_delete/2

Is there anyway to do this in Grails, or at least alternative of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

Grails URL Mappings documentation doesn't help you in this particular case (amra, next time try it yourself and post an answer only if it's any help). Daniel's solution was close, but wouldn't work, because:

1. the action part must be in a closure when created dynamically
2. all named parameters excluding "controller", "action" and "id" are accessible via the params object

A solution could look like this:

```
    "/admin/$controller/$adminAction?/$param?"{
    action = { "admin_${params.adminAction}" }
}
```

The key is NOT to name the parameter as "action", because it seems to be directly mapped to an action and can not be overriden.

I also tried a dynamic solution with generic prefixes and it seems to work as well:

```
    "/$prefix/$controller/$adminAction?/$param?"{
    action = { "${params.prefix}_${params.adminAction}" }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but try this:

```
"mysite/$prefix/$controller/$method/$id?"{
    action = "${prefix}_${method}"
}
```

It constructs the action name from the prefix and the method.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look on grails [URL Mappings documentation part](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html)